# My code can verify self signed certificate but is failing when VeriSign issued certificate is used

Tags: java, security, digital-signature

My application is using java security APIs to sign a file and verify it.
While signing , I am using PFX file and password as inputs and after signing I am generating a signature file using the bytes.
While verification process I am using signature file ,certificate file and the signed file as inputs.
Please find the code I am using in verification below:

```
 // KeyFilePath= path of certificate file
 // fileToVerify = path of signed file
 // signatureFilePath = path of signature file



 InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(KeyFilePath);
 CertificateFactory certificateFactory = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
 X509Certificate x509Certificate = (X509Certificate) certificateFactory.generateCertificate(inputStream);

 // input the signature bytes
 String sigFile = signatureFilePath;

 FileInputStream sigFileInputStream = new FileInputStream(sigFile);
 byte[] sigToVerify = new byte[sigFileInputStream.available()];
 sigFileInputStream.read(sigToVerify);
 sigFileInputStream.close();

 PublicKey pubKey = x509Certificate.getPublicKey();
 Signature signature = Signature.getInstance(signAlgorithm);

 signature.initVerify(pubKey);

 // Update and verify the data
 try {
    FileInputStream dataFileInputStream = new FileInputStream(fileToVerify);
    BufferedInputStream bufferedInputStream = new BufferedInputStream(dataFileInputStream);

    byte[] buffer = new byte[IVerifyDigitalSignature.BYTE_SIZE];
    int bufferedInputStreamLength;

    while (bufferedInputStream.available() != IVerifyDigitalSignature.ZERO_LENGTH) {
        bufferedInputStreamLength = bufferedInputStream.read(buffer);
        signature.update(buffer, IVerifyDigitalSignature.ZERO_LENGTH, bufferedInputStreamLength);
    }

    bufferedInputStream.close();

    // Verify the Signature
    x509Certificate.verify(pubKey);
    verifyDigitalSignature = signature.verify(sigToVerify);
```

Please help me in resolving the same as it is yet not closed.

Comment: `byte[] sigToVerify = new byte[sigFileInputStream.available()];` is documented as an incorrect use of `InputStream.available()`, and so is comparing it to zero as a test for end of stream.

Comment: A self-signed cert is signed by its "own" key, or more exactly by the private half of the keypair whose public half is in the cert. Thus `x509certificate.verify(pubkey)` succeeds, but is basically useless because any attacker can self-sign a fraudulent cert. A CA-signed cert is signed by the CA (private) key, and thus the child cert can be and usually must be verified by locating the *parent* (CA) cert and using *that* pubkey, iterated until you get to the root CA which is self-signed and can be trusted only because it is manually trusted (usually in a truststore file). ...

Comment: ... In addition to valid signatures there are quite a few other things required for a cert chain to be valid (not forged or compromised) that need to be checked. This is generally called PKI validation, or more specifically PKIX validation since that format (X.509 certificates etc. profiled for Internet) is the most common. For Java, http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/certpath/CertPathProgGuide.html is a fairly good place to start.

Comment: Thanks @dave_thompson_085 for your replies.
In my case i need to verify a certificate with three certificate chain in java issue by verisign.
So does it mean i have to iterate three times to reach the root certificate.
From your comment I understood that we need to extract the public key from CA certificate.

Comment: Could you please let me know as to which all inputs i will need to verify the signature i.e. type of certificates ,signature file etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**If you want to do this yourself,** yes you must iterate over the certs in the chain from a trust anchor to your desired cert,
however long that it is (it may vary for different CAs, classes, and at different times).
Verifying the signature on each "child" (lower level) cert using the publickey from the "parent" (next higher) cert is only a
fairly small part of this; there are *many* other steps needed.
Often just *finding* the right certs can be an issue; if you already have a correct chain you have a head start.
But are you sure you have "the" right chain? Frequently there are several possible chains for a given cert,
and sometimes some of them are valid but others have expired or become unverifiable.
Verisign in particular issued I believe all recent certs under their G5 root but provided an alternate path
back to (effectively) G1 for reliers that aren't up to date, and sometimes can't be updated.

The algorithm for most situations is defined in "PKIX" [RFC5280](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5280#section-6),
except that OCSP [RFC6960](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6960) instead of CRL for revocation is becoming more common.
You might get away with omitting cross-hierarchy and NameConstraints, which AFAIK aren't actually used
by public CAs like Verisign, and the Policy stuff which CAs do use but users/reliers don't care about.
https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/37409/certificate-chain-checking has a good but not complete introduction.

But you're **probably better off** using Java's (really JCE's) **CertPathValidator for "PKIX"** -- and if needed CertPathBuilder --
to which I already referred you. This has already been written and tested by experts. Just *calling* it
is still a little bit complicated, but nowhere near as complicated as rewriting all the things it does.

Comment: Thanks a lot @dave_thompson_085 for your detailed expalnation.
I tried the steps mentioned by you and was able to validate a server certificate with its issuer certificate.

Comment: But I would also require to validate the certificates with the "signature" file which was generated while signing process.For this i got an example on https://www.flexiprovider.de/examples/ExampleSMIMEverify.html which solves my problem but it states "The verification of the CA's certificate is possible because the sample certificate is selfsigned. In real life, you would check this certificate chain up to a trusted CA to be sure to have valid certificates."

Comment: So could youplease help me with the java code as to how to resolve "check this certificate chain up to a trusted CA to be sure to have valid certificates"
Thanks in advance